# Is it possible to show that this problem is convex?

Tags: convex-optimization

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}$Consider the following problem
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_x \quad & \Tr(WF(x)) \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & 0 < x \leq 1
\end{aligned} \tag{1}
$$
where $\Tr(\cdot)$ is the trace operator, $W$ is positive semi-definite and
$$
\begin{aligned}
F(x) = \argmax_V \quad & \Tr(V) \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & \begin{bmatrix} AVA^T + Q - V & \sqrt{x}(AVA^T + Q)C^T \\ \sqrt{x} C(AVA^T + Q) & C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \\
\quad & V \succeq 0
\end{aligned} \tag{2}
$$
where $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}, C \in \mathbb R^{m \times n},Q \succeq 0,$ and $R \succ 0$. Suppose that there exists a $V \succeq 0$ such that $AVA^T + Q - V \succeq 0$. Note that the positive semi-definiteness constraint in $(2)$ is equivalent to (via the Schur complement lemma) the following "modified" algebraic Riccati inequality:
$$
AVA^T + Q - V - x(AVA^T + Q)C^T(C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R)^{-1}C(AVA^T + Q) \succeq 0
$$
**Question**: Assuming that $(2)$ has a unique solution for every value of $x \in (0,1]$ (such that $F$ in $(2)$ is well-defined on $(0,1]$), is it possible to show that the problem in $(1)$ is convex? I'm trying to prove this by showing that $F(x)$ is convex in $x$. However, given that $x$ appears in the constraint in $(2)$, I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: This is a bi-level optimization problem, so I believe non-convex.  But you could grid in $x$, and solve the convex optimization problem (2) for each fixed grid value of $x$. Then pick the best value of $x$, with its corresponding optimal value of $V$.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone thanks for the feedback. Will definitely look into grid search. Out of curiosity, are bilevel optimization problems always non-convex?

Comment: Some trivial) bi-level problems can be expressed (formulated) as single level convex problems.

Comment: Since $x$ is a scalar on $(0, 1]$, this is really just "line search" in the outer level, and since the inner problem is convex, this approach is likely to work well.

Comment: @Max thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}$It seems that $x = 1$ should solve $(1)$. My reasoning for this is as follows.

Because $x \neq 0$, then $\frac{1}{x}$ always exists, and so the constraint
$$
\begin{bmatrix} AVA^T + Q - V & \sqrt{x}(AVA^T + Q)C^T \\ \sqrt{x} C(AVA^T + Q) & C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
$$
in $(2)$ can be transformed as follows
$$
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix} AVA^T + Q - V & \sqrt{x}(AVA^T + Q)C^T \\ \sqrt{x} C(AVA^T + Q) & C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \\
&\iff AVA^T + Q - V - x(AVA^T + Q)C^T(C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R)^{-1}C(AVA^T + Q) \succeq 0 \\
&\iff AVA^T + Q - V - (AVA^T + Q)C^T\left(\frac{1}{x}[C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R]\right)^{-1}C(AVA^T + Q) \succeq 0 \\
&\iff \begin{bmatrix} AVA^T + Q - V & (AVA^T + Q)C^T \\ C(AVA^T + Q) & \frac{1}{x}[C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R] \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \\
&\iff \begin{bmatrix} AVA^T + Q - V & (AVA^T + Q)C^T \\ C(AVA^T + Q) & 0 \end{bmatrix} + \frac{1}{x}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \\
&\iff \begin{bmatrix} AVA^T + Q - V & (AVA^T + Q)C^T \\ C(AVA^T + Q) & 0 \end{bmatrix} \succeq -\frac{1}{x}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
Because $\frac{1}{x} \in [1,\infty)$ and the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R \end{bmatrix}
$$
is positive semi-definite (since $R$ is positive definite and $AVA^T + Q$ is positive semi-definite), then the matrix
$$
-\frac{1}{x}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R \end{bmatrix}
$$
is negative semi-definite for every $x \in (0,1]$.

Moreover, as $x$ decreases from $1$ towards $0$, the feasible set in $(2)$ gets larger in the following sense. Fix any $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $(0,1]$ such that $x_1 < x_2$. Then,
$$
-\frac{1}{x_1}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R \end{bmatrix} \prec -\frac{1}{x_2}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R \end{bmatrix}
$$
and so
$$
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix} AVA^T + Q - V & (AVA^T + Q)C^T \\ C(AVA^T + Q) & 0 \end{bmatrix} \succeq -\frac{1}{x_2}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R \end{bmatrix} \\
&\implies \begin{bmatrix} AVA^T + Q - V & (AVA^T + Q)C^T \\ C(AVA^T + Q) & 0 \end{bmatrix} \succeq -\frac{1}{x_1}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, the set
$$
\mathcal G(x_2) = \left\{V \succeq 0 \ \Bigg| \begin{bmatrix} AVA^T + Q - V & (AVA^T + Q)C^T \\ C(AVA^T + Q) & 0 \end{bmatrix} \succeq -\frac{1}{x_2}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R \end{bmatrix}\right\}
$$
is a subset of
$$
\mathcal G(x_1) = \left\{V \succeq 0 \ \Bigg| \begin{bmatrix} AVA^T + Q - V & (AVA^T + Q)C^T \\ C(AVA^T + Q) & 0 \end{bmatrix} \succeq -\frac{1}{x_1}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & C(AVA^T + Q)C^T + R \end{bmatrix}\right\}
$$
for every $x_1 < x_2$ and $x_1,x_2 \in (0,1]$.

Furthermore, because the objective function in $(2)$ is $\Tr(V)$, a linear and monotonically increasing function of $V$, then $\argmax_V \Tr(V)$ should either increase or stay the same as the size of the feasible set increases, which occurs when $x$ decreases.

The rate of increase of the size of the feasible set, however, cannot be constant, as the map $x \mapsto -\frac{1}{x}$ has a nonlinearly decreasing rate of increase. Therefore, $F(x)$ cannot be a linear function of $x$.

To conclude, although some additional precision can be added to the preceding argument, one would expect $F(x)$ to be a monotonically decreasing function of $x$, such that $x = 1$ solves the problem in $(1)$.